# How to output 'Event Source' field for attendees of an event?

Tags: civievent, civireport

I am using the Event Source field to record table hosts for an event. However, the event reports do not have the option to select 'event source' as an output column...

Do I need to make a custom report? (A little past my experience level after finding https://sf2012.civicrm.org/sites/default/files/slides/CiviCRM%20Reports-Customize%20and%20Extend.pdf, but can be done).

Is there a better way to organize a table host event in CiviCRM? Or should I rather create a custom contact field and just use that?

Comment: if you are on drupal it may be worth exploring if Views gives you what you need

Comment: you may also want to clarify what a 'table host' means to you. why not create a custom field for 'events' and use a Contact Reference field so you can actually link to a contact in your db?

Answer (score 1):

"Source" is available in the reports as of Civi 4.7.2: see [CRM-18042](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18042).

So one option is to upgrade to Civi 4.7.  Another option is to backport the patch, which is a lot less work than a custom report.  I'd give it a 95% chance that you can simply insert [the lines from the patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7811/files) into the appropriate file on 4.6 and it'll just work.